# Set wrap_content to layout_height in PullToRefreshListView

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I set wrap_content to layout_height in PullToRefreshListView in my layout.
PullToRefreshListView has a header.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@color/my_investment_list_bg">
<View
        android:layout_width="3px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dip"
        android:background="@color/timeline"/>
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, when start this activity, only the header shows, even if I have some data and notifyDataSetChanged.
I don't want to set match_parent to layout_height in PullToRefreshListView. Because, if there's no data in the list, I wanna show the header and another view between the bottom of the header and the bottom of the screen.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you check when you set match_parent then is showing data ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana I checked that and everything's works fine.

Comment: so you have added header and footer at run time to this PullToRefreshListView ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana Only header no footer. I tried to add a footer and put some views in, try set match parent to the footer, but it doesn't works. The footer still looks like to be set wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in my project. The problem is with this type of list, because it can be shown in this kind of structure of layouts if it has this attribute setup android:layout_height="match_parent" So, in this case i leave it like this, and i changed the height programmatically to be wrap_content, after i populate my list, something like this: `mMyListView.getRefreshableView().getLayoutParams().height=RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
mMyListView.getRefreshableView().requestLayout();`